# Write a function to determine whether an array contains consecutive numbers for at least N numbers

Tags: javascript, algorithm, array

I am trying to write a function to determine whether an array contains consecutive numbers for at least N numbers. For example, the input is `[1,5,3,4]` and `3`, it turns `true` because the array has `3` consecutive numbers, which is `[3,4,5]`

Here this function requires sorting beforehand and it is not the most eloquent solution in my opinion. Can someone take a look and suggest some improvements on this?

```js
function hasConsecutiveNums(array, N) {
  if (array.length < N) return false;
  if (N === 0) return true;
  const sortedArray = array.slice().sort((a, b) => a - b);
  let count = 0;
  let prev = null;
  for (const num of sortedArray) {
    if (prev && num === prev + 1) {
      count++;
    } else {
      count = 1;
    }
    if (count === N) return true;
    prev = num;
  }

  return false;
}

console.log(hasConsecutiveNums([1, 4, 5, 6], 3)) // true
console.log(hasConsecutiveNums([1, 4, 5, 6], 4)) // false
```

Comment: Would the case `[1, 4, 5, 5, 6], 3`  be expected to return true? in the current code it doesn't

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One issue to consider: what if an element in the array is 0, and thus falsey? Then `if (prev &&` will not be fulfilled:

```
console.log(hasConsecutiveNums([-1, 0, 1], 3)) // false... oops
```

```js
function hasConsecutiveNums(array, N) {
  if (array.length < N) return false;
  if (N === 0) return true;
  const sortedArray = array.slice().sort((a, b) => a - b);
  let count = 0;
  let prev = null;
  for (const num of sortedArray) {
    if (prev && num === prev + 1) {
      count++;
    } else {
      count = 1;
    }
    if (count === N) return true;
    prev = num;
  }

  return false;
}

console.log(hasConsecutiveNums([-1, 0, 1], 3)) // false... oops
```

Another tweak to make the code a bit more elegant would be to assign `prev` to the first element of the array first, and initialize `count` to `1`, thus starting comparison on the *second* element rather than on the first, avoiding the need to compare against `null`.

With this method, you also need to return `true` immediately if the array's length is only 1, like the other answer recommends, otherwise there won't be any iterations within which `return true` could be reached:

```js
function hasConsecutiveNums(array, N) {
  if (array.length < N) return false;
  if (N <= 1) return true;
  const sortedArray = array.slice().sort((a, b) => a - b);
  let prev = sortedArray.shift();
  let count = 1; // first element of the array is already in prev
  for (const num of sortedArray) {
    if (num === prev + 1) {
      count++;
    } else {
      count = 1;
    }
    if (count === N) return true;
    prev = num;
  }

  return false;
}

console.log(hasConsecutiveNums([1, 4, 5, 6], 3)) // true
console.log(hasConsecutiveNums([1, 4, 5, 6], 4)) // false
console.log(hasConsecutiveNums([-1, 0, 1], 3)) // true
```

If, as the comment notes, you'd want `[1, 2, 2, 3]` to return `true`, de-duplicate the numbers with a Set:

```js
function hasConsecutiveNums(array, N) {
  if (array.length < N) return false;
  if (N <= 1) return true;
  const sortedArray = [...new Set(array.slice().sort((a, b) => a - b))];
  let prev = sortedArray.shift();
  let count = 1; // first element of the array is already in prev
  for (const num of sortedArray) {
    if (num === prev + 1) {
      count++;
    } else {
      count = 1;
    }
    if (count === N) return true;
    prev = num;
  }

  return false;
}

console.log(hasConsecutiveNums([1, 4, 5, 6], 3)) // true
console.log(hasConsecutiveNums([1, 4, 5, 6], 4)) // false
console.log(hasConsecutiveNums([-1, 0, 1], 3)) // true
console.log(hasConsecutiveNums([1, 2, 2, 3], 3)) // true
```

Comment: Thanks for incorporating my comment into you answer, keeps my lazy butt for having to write my own :P

Answer (score 1):

Some quick remarks:

```
if (N === 0) return true;
```

can be replaced by

```
if (N <= 1) return true;
```

because in a non-empty array each element is a single “consecutive number.” This saves the sorting of the array in the case \$ N = 1 \$.

Then it suffices to check the count again only if it has been incremented.

The comparison with the previous number (or `null`) can be simplified slightly.

```
  for (const num of sortedArray) {
    if (prev === num - 1) {
      count++;
      if (count === N) return true;
    } else {
      count = 1;
    }
    prev = num;
  }
```