# Design a simple card game in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, object-oriented, game, playing-cards

I wrote a simple card game in JavaScript and I wonder if anyone could give me some advice and make some improvements on my code.

Here is the demo that I build: 
https://codesandbox.io/s/cardgame-his95?file=/src/index.js

So it is a 2 person card game. Every card has a number and also has a pattern. 
The game goes like this: we have a set of pre-defined rules, and these rules have a ranking. The player that satisfies the highest-ranked rule will win. And there could be tie if they end up with the same ranking. The goal here is not just to make the game work, also I wanted to account for maintainability. For example, we can easily add new rules and swap the ranking and re-define the rule if possible.

There are mainly a couple of classes.
First is the `Game` class

```js
class Game {
  constructor({ play1, play2, rules, messages }) {
    this.play1 = play1;
    this.play2 = play2;
    this.rules = rules;
    this.messages = messages;
  }
  play() {
    let rankOfP1 = Infinity;
    let rankOfP2 = Infinity;
    for (const rule of this.rules) {
      if (rule.validator(this.play1)) {
        rankOfP1 = rule.rank;
        break;
      }
    }
    for (const rule of this.rules) {
      if (rule.validator(this.play2)) {
        rankOfP2 = rule.rank;
        break;
      }
    }

    return rankOfP1 === rankOfP2
      ? this.messages.tie
      : rankOfP1 < rankOfP2
      ? this.messages.win.player1
      : this.messages.win.player2;
  }
}
```

Here the `rules` are an array of `rule` object where every object looks like this

```js
{
    description: "Six Cards of the same pattern",
    rank: 1,
    validator: cards => {
      return hasSamePattern(cards, 6);
    }
```

The lower the rank gets, the more important this rule is. So If `player1` satisfies a `rule` with rank `1`, and `player1` satisfies a `rule` with rank `2`, then we say `player1` won.
And `validator` is the function that takes an array of `card` object and returns a boolean to determine if the set of cards satisfy the rule.

And lastly we have a `Card` class which is pretty simple

```js
class Card {
  constructor({ pattern, number }) {
    this.pattern = pattern;
    this.number = number;
  }
}
```

Please take a look and feel free to make some improvements on it. Also please suggest some better naming for variables if possible, I am not a native English speaker so some of the names of the variables would be a bit weird.

Finally I wrote this game in a OOP style. I know that JavaScript is not the best language out there when it comes to OOP. Also I am not really good at Object Oriented Design. I wonder if anyone knows how to rewrite the game in **functional programming style**. That would be super cool!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your constructor has

```
constructor({ play1, play2, rules, messages }) {
  this.play1 = play1;
  this.play2 = play2;
  this.rules = rules;
  this.messages = messages;
}
```

You may as well `Object.assign` the parameter to the instance instead:

```
constructor(config) {
  Object.assign(this, config);
}
```

`pattern` is a slightly odd name for what it represents here - the usual English word for one of the clubs, diamonds, etc, is **suit**. `rule` is a bit strange as well - a rule usually refers to the process by which a game is played (eg "Hands consist of 6 cards" or "The player with the best hand wins"). To describe the different possible winning combinations and their ranks, I'd use the word `handRanks` [or something similar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_poker_hands). `play1` and `play2` aren't great descriptors either - these represent the cards held in each player's hand, so maybe use `player1Cards` or `player1Hand`.

With regards to the `play()` method, when you want to find an item in an array which fulfills a condition, it would be more appropriate to use `.find`, rather than a `for` loop - `find` more clearly indicates what the intention of the loop is, and is more concise. You also need to set the rank to `Infinity` if no handRanks pass - why not integrate this `Infinity` into the `handRanks` array itself? You're also writing the looping code twice - you can make it more DRY by putting it into a function, and calling that function twice instead.

```
new Card({ suit: "spade", number: 1 }),  // <-- Suit
```

```
new HandRank({  // <-- HandRank
  description: "Six Cards of the same suit",  // <-- Suit
  rank: 1,
  validator: cards => {
    return hasSameSuit(cards, 6);  // <-- hasSameSuit, not hasSamePattern
  }
}),
new HandRank({  // <-- HandRank
  description: "Nothing special",
  rank: Infinity,                 // <-- add this whole new HandRank
  validator: cards => true,
}),
```

```
getRank(cards) {
  return this.handRanks.find(({ validator }) => validator(cards)).rank; // <-- this.handRanks
}
play() {
  const rankOfP1 = this.getRank(this.player1Cards); //  <-- player1Cards
  const rankOfP2 = this.getRank(this.player2Cards); //  <-- player2Cards
  return rankOfP1 === rankOfP2
    ? this.messages.tie
    : rankOfP1 < rankOfP2
      ? this.messages.win.player1
      : this.messages.win.player2;
}
```

One of the benefits of using arrow functions is that if the function contains only a single expression which is immediately returned, you can omit the `{` `}` brackets and the `return` keyword, if you want to make things concise, eg for the `hasSameSuit` test above:

```
validator: cards => hasSameSuit(cards, 6),
```

If you want to find if any item in an array *passes* a test, but you don't care about *which* item passes the test, you should use `.some`, not `.find`. (`.some` returns a boolean indicating whether any passed, `.find` returns the found item) For the `hasSamePattern` (or `hasSameSuit`) method, use:

```
return Object.values(patterns).some(num => num >= threshold);
```

Your `hasConsecutiveNums` method has the bug [mentioned in the comments previously](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/240914/write-a-function-to-determine-whether-an-array-contains-consecutive-numbers-for/240918#comment472670_240914) - a hand of `[1, 2, 2, 3]` will not pass a 3-consecutive-number test because the sorted array will contain 2 twice, failing `if (prevNum + 1 === num) {`. De-duplicate the numbers with a Set first.

```
const nums = [...new Set(cards.map(card => card.number).sort((a, b) => a - b))];
```

> I wonder if anyone knows how to rewrite the game in functional programming style.

Javascript isn't *entirely* suited to completely functional programming either, though it can get most of the way there. To start with, make your functions pure, and avoid side-effects and mutations. For example, assigning to a property of the instance with `this.play1 = play1;` (or `this.player1Cards = player1Cards;`) is a mutation. None of your code *fundamentally* requires anything non-functional (except the `console.log` at the very end, which is unavoidable), so it should be pretty easy to convert - rather than assigning to properties, just keep the variables in a closure, and return a function for the `play` method, eg:

```
const makeGame = ({ player1Cards, player2Cards, handRanks, messages }) => () => {
  // getRank is now a standalone function which takes a handRanks parameter
  const rankOfP1 = getRank(player1Cards, handRanks);
  const rankOfP2 = getRank(player2Cards, handRanks);
  return rankOfP1 === rankOfP2
    ? messages.tie
    : rankOfP1 < rankOfP2
      ? messages.win.player1
      : messages.win.player2;
};
```

```
const play = makeGame({ ... });
console.log(play());
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for such a thorough answer! I'd like to ask more questions about functional programming. In your opinion, is it better to write this game in a functional programming style or OO style? If we were using functional programming here. Do we still need to use `new` to initialize all those objects like `card` objects, `player` objects, and `HandRank` object?

Comment: Both work, it's purely a matter of preference. Personally, I'd strongly prefer to go the functional method, but someone else might think differently. *Do we still need to use new* No, usually, if you're trying to be functional, you should not use `new`, because that indicates that you're mutating somewhere.

Comment: But in this script, your `new Card` and `new Rule`s don't accomplish anything useful - all they do is create objects with properties. Using a plain object instead would make more sense IMO. Eg `const rules = [
  {
    description: "Six Cards of the same pattern",
    rank: 1,
    validator: cards => {
      return hasSamePattern(cards, 6);
    }
  }, ...` Classes are useful when you want to *bundle data with methods*. Data alone or functions alone don't have a reason to be in classes IMO. Use a class when you need data *and methods associated with the data*.

Comment: if we ditch `new`, but I find using object literal doesn't scale well and you need to write it every time you need a new `card` or `rule`, is there a functional way to produce objects? And can you show me how to do it in the code?

Comment: When all you need is a data structure, like here, using an object literal scales *better* than using `new` - it requires less code and (IMO) is easier to understand intuitively (compared with having to go to the constructor definition to see what's going on).`new Card({ suit: "spade", number: 1 })` vs `{ suit: "spade", number: 1 }` - since Card doesn't have any methods, there's no point to the `new`.

Comment: The easiest way to produce objects would be to just use the object literals themselves. You could also do `const makeObj = obj => obj`, but that's silly. `const makeCard = ({ suit, number }) => ({ suit, number })` is silly too